# Reachability stops working

Tags: iphone, ios10, xcode8

In the beginning, Reachability works. I double tap home button and the screen slides down. When I double tap again, the screen goes back up. This happens on UITableViewController, which is showing the list of items.

I present a new UIViewController with a text view for typing new entry or editing existing one. Reachability still works on this VC. No issue here.

The problem starts after I dismiss the second VC I mentioned, which is UIViewController that I use for editing purpose. Reachability no longer works when I come back to UITableViewController. The screen still slides down, but it doesn't stay there. It comes back up immediately, like something is cancelling the act.

What can be preventing the Reachability from working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself. It turned out I was repeating NSTimer without invalidating when dismissing the top UIViewController.

I solved it by, first, assigning the timer to a property

```
 _timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.2 target:self selector:@selector(dismissWriter) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

and then, in viewWillDisappear

```
[_timer invalidate];
_timer = nil;
```

Now, the UITableViewController underneath works with Reachability. Hope my mistake might help someone.